# How do I see Inner Details for a bicep deployment?

Tags: azure, azure-bicep, azure-deployment

I deploy a bicep with this powershell command:

```
New-AzResourceGroupDeployment -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -Mode Incremental -TemplateFile .\appservice_linux.bicep -TemplateParameterObject $templateParameters -Verbose
```

The deployment is failing, with this error:

> Error: Code=InvalidTemplateDeployment; Message=The template deployment
> 'appservice_linux' is not valid according to the validation procedure.
> The tracking id is '3af29b5f-342a-48fe-8017-6459490c15fd'. See inner
> errors for details.

How do I see the inner error with the details?

Is there a parameter to New-AzResourceGroupDeployment that will return it?

There are no deployments in the Azure UI. Shouldn't I see the trackingID here?

[image]

Comment: Hi Don, the validation failed so the template is not dpeloyed. Any bicep error / warning showing up  ?

Comment: @don Chambers - Could you please add the `--debug` in your `New-AzResourceGroupDeployment` cmdlet to know more why the deployment got failed.

Comment: It would be too hard to identify the issue by looking at the error message, It would be better if you can add the sample bicep template and parameters that you are using that would be helpful to check further

Comment: @VenkateshDodda
A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument '--debug'.

Comment: @DonChambers sorry for the confusion here. If you are deploying from powershell you need to use `-debug` and for bash you need to use `--debug`

Comment: When I do that I get: CloseError: PowerShell is in NonInteractive mode. Read and Prompt functionality is not available.